# 3D model format with multiple UV coords and custom attributes per vertex

Tags: 3d, 3d-modelling

Let's say I am using a custom GLSL shader that uses a special interleaved array format made of 11 floats :position (3 floats), normal (3 floats),UVcoord-1 (2 floats), UVcoord-2 (2 floats),custom attribute (1 float).

I need a file format (preferably ASCII) that allows me to export all this information (especially multiple UV coords for multi-texturing) per vertex from a 3D modelling software (eg. Blender, Maya,etc) and then import it to my application. I have searched all over the net, I can't seem to find a format that allows multiple(custom) data channels per vertex.Am I missing something obvious?

For example:I am using .OBJ format and it only seems to export position, normal and 1 texture to be exported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just define your very own format? If you're looking for something ready to use, have a look at OpenCTM http://openctm.sourceforge.net

Comment: Well, even if I define my own file format, I still need an exporter to get the data from the modelling app. It would seem to me in this day of shaders and non-fixed-pipeline that the old pos/normal/texture formats would quickly become obsolete. Odd that I cannot find a popular format that allows me to save a 3D model to be easily processed into a vertex array to be sent to a shader.

Comment: @Radu094: How do you define "popular"? You were asking about ASCII based formats. Writing and reading such kind of formats is easy enough, if you don't add a lot of XML-esque mubo-jumbo to it. So usually people tend to just implement their very own formats. Also there's COLLADA (XML hell) and the OpenCTM I already linked. Don't feel obliged to use some ancient format, that people claim to be a standard.

Comment: @Radu094: Writing an exporter for Blender is easy enough. OpenCTM also ships one. The same goes for any other 3D modeller I know about.

Comment: OpenCTM seems right on the money.Just a few more steps to arrange the entire pipeline from modeller->OpenCTM->applicaton, but it looks very promissing. Thanks!